# Cannot disable buttons (reactive forms)

Tags: javascript, button, bootstrap-4, angular6

I know its an easy question but it dont want to work... I have a reactive form with validations and I simply want the button to be disabled while the form group is not valid.

I know how to solve this. Just by this line.. normally: [disabled]="!fg_profile"
But the button is always enabled. On clicking the button I let the console output the state of the formgroup and it says the formgroup is not valid (false). But still the button is enabled...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                (click)="updateProfile(fg_profile.value)"
                [disabled]="!fg_profile">{{'control.save' | translate }}</button>
```

This is my button.

```
    this.fg_profile = this.fb.group({
    password: [null, [Validators.minLength(6)]],
    password_confirm: [null, [Validators.minLength(6)]],
    email: [null, [emailValidator, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    jabber: [null, [emailValidator, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    current_password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
  },
  {
    // check whether our password and confirm password match
    validator: PasswordValidation.passwordMatchValidator
  });
```

This is my validation part in typescript.

As I tol you the button is always enabled. I also tried to do something like this: [disabled]="true"
But still it is enabled... Whats wrong here?

Comment: have you tried  [disabled]="fg_profile.invalid" or [attr.disabled]="fg_profile.invalid"

Comment: nope, stil enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding your disabled attribute to fg_profile.valid. That should fix it provided your validation logic is correct.

In your logic, I cannot see you using the FormControl. Ensure you use this and also import the necessary Form dependencies as well. FORMGROUP, FORM CONTROL AND VALIDATORS FROM @angular/forms

Comment: oh yes I tried that. I tried so much that I forgot to write the .valid at the end.